# Find all children of top parent in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have a list of parent-child relations where the structure isn't a true tree. Some parents can have many children and also some children can have more than one parent.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([[123,234],[123,235],[123,236],[124,236],[234,345],[236,346]], columns=['Parent','Child'])*
```

I would like to group all children for specific ancestors. From the data:

```
123,234,235,236,345,346
124,235,346
```

Should be the correct groups.

I tried with:

```
parents = set()
children = {}
for p, c in df.to_records(index=False).tolist():
    parents.add(p)
    children[c] = p


def getAncestors(p):
    return (getAncestors(children[p]) if p in children else []) + [p]
```

But on 346 it only returns one group.

Also, how to then find all children for 123 and 124?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you considered using a lib like networkx ?

Comment: Determine nodes that are not the child of any other node, then do DFS from each of those?

Comment: Actually, solved the problem using networkx. Created MultiDiGraph, converted to Graph to create clusters and than applied nx.ancestors to get the parents. Thanks for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, it's not really a tree, but more like a directed acyclic graph, so you can't map each child to just one parent; it'd have to be a list of parents. Also, given your use case, I'd suggest mapping parents to their lists of children instead.

```
relations = [[123,234],[234,345],[123,235],[123,236],[124,236],[236,346]]

children = {}
for p, c in relations:
    children.setdefault(p, []).append(c)
roots = set(children) - set(c for cc in children.values() for c in cc)
```

You can then use a recursive function similar to the one you already have to get all the children to a given root node (or any parent node). The root itself is not in the list, but can easily be added.

```
def all_children(p):
    if p not in children:
        return set()
    return set(children[p] + [b for a in children[p] for b in all_children(a)])

print({p: all_children(p) for p in roots})
# {123: {234, 235, 236, 345, 346}, 124: {346, 236}}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I must now rewrite getAncestors function to fit new children structure.